# Live MJPEG Solution for IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, mjpeg

**Short/TLDR:** I am looking for a way to show a live MJPEG stream on a HTTP server with a client running IE6 (Windows CE).

**Background:** I am not a programmer, I am an electrical engineer by trade. The reason for such an odd request is that we have an HMI machine from RockWell AB called PanelView. For some God forsaken reason, this machine runs Windows CE, which runs IE6(in 2019).

I've got a Raspberry Pi that has NodeJS installed, and can capture a MJPEG stream from FFMPEG, or any other video capture tool.

It's a simple problem if you don't have to use a browser from the early 2000s. I've used a `multipart/x-mixed-replace` solution, which IE doesn't support, and I've used a Socket based solution: https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg which works fantastic on every browser except IE10 and less. Unfortunately, the client side `jsmpeg.min.js` uses `WebSocket` and `Canvas`, which are not supported in IE6.

I've looked over this solution, Paparazzo: https://github.com/defvol/Paparazzo.js

I'm not sure if it would work, and it is currently moot, as the client side requires `JQuery`:

demo/demo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Active camera will refresh every 2 seconds
                var TIMEOUT = 2000;
                var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 31));
                    $('img#camera').attr('src', 'http://localhost:3000/camera?i=' + Math.random());
                }, TIMEOUT);    
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="" id="camera">
    </body>
</html>
```

The basic problem with these solutions is I don't know JavaScript well enough to make any changes aside from copy/paste. I don't need anyone to do this for me, but I would like to know SO's opinion if this is a fool's errand or not.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't remember IE6, you have a still image displayed? If, so the last code snippet is what you need, and you could use a very old version of jQuery if you fear newest won't work on IE6, or you could also convert this snippet quite easily to `window.onload = function() { setInterval( function() { document.getElementById('camera').src = 'camera?i=' + Math.random(); }, 2000); };` which would do the same and should work in Netscape ;-).

Comment: I don't understand the use of `Math.random` for this.

Comment: @EmettSpeer `url + "?foo=" + uniq_val` will force the browser to not use the cache, because it could be an entirely different response depending on the params. This is needed here because the browser is not able to handle mjpeg stream (i.e to update only what it needs at regular intervals), so we set up this system manually. If we allowed the use of the cache, we would always use the same still image, which is not what we want either.. However, in a supporting browser, we would only load the diff between two frames, while here we will load the whole file at every frames. But no other way...

Comment: I didn't even think of the caching issue.